# What is the between function application and calling a function?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I hear the term "function application" used (mostly related to Haskell), and it seems like it just means "calling a function". The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_application) basically calls it a mathematical term for calling a function:

> In mathematics, function application is the act of applying a function to an argument from its domain so as to obtain the corresponding value from its range.

What is the difference between calling a function and function application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barebones explanation:

Haskell and other functional languages are much more abstractly mathematical as far as what a function is for.

In a procedural language you call a function, which is a collection of statements which may or may not operate on data.

In a functional language you have data, and you apply a function to it to do something with the data.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function seems to imply that you are invoking a runtime operation in a programming language, which will execute an abstraction to figure out the results of what a function does. Function application seems more like a generalized term to use when we'd like to talk about... function application... at any time, e.g.: at compile-time, syntactically, or mathematically.

Function application may also refer to `apply`. Historically in various programming languages, `apply` is a higher-order function that takes a function reference, an argument list, and whose result should be f(argument list).

In Haskell, function application most likely refers to currying a function by one argument. In Haskell, all you need are spaces to *represent* function application (the `$` operator does nothing but change the precedence/grouping, to allow less parentheses; as opposed to LISP). Contrast this with the "normal" notation we learn in basic algebra and use in non-functional programming, where `f(a,b,c)` represents the function f applied to arguments `a,b,c`. I don't think you'd use the term "call a function" unless you were dealing with an abstraction that actually called functions; which I'm not even sure Haskell has. Haskell might for example have an abstraction which reduces functions by pattern-matching... or using "call a function" might be reasonable in Haskell.